# How to show the value of a variable in vim latex-suite

Tags: vim, vim-latex

Is there a way to show the current value of a Latex-Suite variable, e.g. g:Tex_DefaultTargetFormat, from the vim command line?

Comment: found it:

    :echo g:Tex_DefaultTargetFormat

I tried that before, but it didn't work because the plugin was not loaded (I am new to vim and Latex-Suite)

Comment: welcome to tex.sx, do you want to post (and accept) a self-answer, or we could close the question as "too localised". It is your choice really, but we don't like to leave questions technically unanswered:-)

Comment: I can't answer myself now because I am new. I have to wait for a few hours.

Comment: Also, I have to agree that this question is probably too localised as I did not realize that it works with the usual vim commands. So I am fine with closing it.